# Discover BLE services from OS X using [aPeripheral discoverServices:@[servUUID]];

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Do you know if there is any difference to use this method

```
 #define BLINKY_SERVICE_UUID             @"00000001-59a4-4d2b-8479-8bbdbcf77fcd" 

CBUUID *servUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:SERVICE_UUID];
[aPeripheral setDelegate:self];
[aPeripheral discoverServices:@[servUUID]];
```

from an iPad, iPhone or MacAir 10.9.5 ? I am using it through the MacAir 10.9.5 and I don't discover the custom service I was supposed to (SERVICE_UUID). Only the common services :

```
Discovered characteristic Device Name for sevice Generic Access Profile 
Discovered characteristic Appearence for sevice Generic Access Profile 
Discovered characteristic Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters for sevice Generic Access Profile 
Discovered characteristic Unknown (<2a37>) for sevice Unknown (<180d>) 
Discovered characteristic Unknown (<2a38>) for sevice Unknown (<180d>) 
Discovered characteristic Battery Level for sevice Battery 
Discovered characteristic Manufacturer Name String for sevice Device Information
```

and I don't have an iPhone or iPad to test it right now

Comment: There should be no difference.  Have you tried passing `nil` instead of the services array and confirming that the service you are looking for is there?

Comment: Yes, in fact, when I pass nil [aPeripheral discoverServices:nil] I can see the common services; passing [aPeripheral discoverServices:@[servUUID]] I can't discover any service, because i am specifying the common one

Comment: Perhaps if you should what SERVICE_UUID is

Comment: is the UUID (the same that in the perihperal, I've checked it)

Comment: The UUID of the peripheral or the UUID of the service?  If it isn't one of the UUIDs listed above then your peripheral isn't offering that service

Comment: is the UUID of the service.... aparently not, but I debugged the peripheral where I programmed the service in C and everything seems to be fine...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65914/discussion-between-paulw11-and-darkzone).

Comment: the UUID of the service